# Jquery: How to validation is successfully done?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am creating a simple form that contains text fields.

These text fields are saved on change events using Ajax.

My question is i want to validate(jquery) these fields before change event.

Please, help. Thanks....... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').change(function(){
  vat retrn = validatethisfield();
if(retrn == false)
{
//show msg;
return false;
}

})
```

In this validate this field function , do your validation and return false if invalid data...

Answer (score 0):

Do validation on [blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) or [focusout](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/)

Answer (score 0):

Or on your submit button , use
validation function.

```
<input type="submit" value= "submit it" onclick= "javascript:return formvalidator()">
```

always return true
unless a text box is empty or something of that nature

```
function formvalidator(){
var test = true;

if($trim.$("#myTextField").val()) == " "){
alert('Empty!!');
test = false;
}

return test;
}
```

Comment: I dont have submit button. I saving fields on change event of text fields using ajax call.

Comment: then put the content of my formvalidator inside your change event

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this, thou plugins are readily available,for start you can learn you can write your code which is very easy to learn one of link you can refer is this one....

It covers almost all aspect of form validation:

[link](http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/form-validation-using-jquery-and-regular-expressions/)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery.ajax has a beforeSend. You can do your validations in this function.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/some/path',
  beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
    // do your validations here
  },
  success: function( data ) {
    // handle success
  }
});
```

To quote jquery's [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> beforeSend(jqXHR, settings) - A pre-request callback function
>   that can be used to modify the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest)
>   object before it is sent. Use this to set custom headers, etc. The
>   jqXHR and settings maps are passed as arguments. This is an Ajax
>   Event. Returning false in the beforeSend function will cancel the
>   request. As of jQuery 1.5, the beforeSend option will be called
>   regardless of the type of request.